# I cannot write or find a single example of JavaScript that will display in any of my browsers

Tags: javascript

I am just learning Javascript, and cannot get find a way to get Javascript to display in any browser, whether embedded in the HTML or in a external file. This is the example I am currently trying:

```
<script>
prompt(‘Hey!’)
</script>
```

and I am getting this error:

[Google Chrome Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeJUT.png)

I am sure I'm doing something silly, but I cannot figure out what for the life of me.

Comment: Don't use "smart quotes".

Comment: change it to `prompt("hey")` and it will work! `alert("hey")` would prob be clearer

Comment: <script>
prompt('Hey!');
</script> try this you are using wrong quotes

Comment: For your reference: [a way to make DOM elements with JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp).  It is very simple and a nice way to start out.  Also, if you are using JS for interacting with DOM elements, [`getElementById()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) will be VERY useful.  Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can write directly to Chrome console like alert('Hello world!'); or any other basic code just to try. 
Other suggestion is using https://plnkr.co . Its a developer tool you can edit using your browser.